# Is it impolite to use the word "snog"?

Tags: british-english

My ex-wife always used this word instead of "kiss". She even used the verb "snogging" in some semi-formal places. She is not a native speaker however she has studied English literature for many years. She insisted that the word is a slang and informal but NOT rude in anyway.

Comment: This is British English, not American English, so I, a "native speaker" don't know the answer to this one.

Comment: SNOG is a (neutral) slang word. Of course, most *all* words *can* be used in a rude or impolite manner; but in English, that depends more on tone or context. Without any rude tone, *snog* does not have any innate rude qualities to it. [Examples](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/snog). [More examples](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/snog)

Comment: EX-wife.. please

Comment: It's a word that is most frequently used in the playground and by adolescents -  adults primarily use it when they're taking the mickey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very rude or impolite, but it's not exactly romantic either. You *can*, however, use it to describe particularly obnoxious kissing, and as such can be misunderstood that way.

"Those two were kissing on the bus like there was nobody else around!" carries a fairly pleasant tone, kind of admiration - it's something you could put in a happy ending of a romance novel. But if you say "Those two were snogging on the bus(...)", it sounds somewhat harsher - either you got annoyed by the obnoxiousness, or are jokingly poking fun at the kissers.

It all depends on the context, but "kiss" carries a bit more romantic inclinations. "Snog" is more... physical. It's best to take a look at the [BNC](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=snog&mysubmit=Go), or any other corpus, to get a feel for the context for this word.

Comment: It could be that the meaning is still changing, but AIUI, the normal usage would be "kiss & cuddle", with no negative connotations.

Comment: I had never heard of the BNC.  Fascinating!